# Error when installing PECL Oauth Extension on CentOS 5.6

Tags: php, pecl, oauth

I'm trying to install the PECL OAuth extension on CentOS 5.6, I have all the required dependencies installed, but I can't get past this error:

```
downloading oauth-1.1.0.tgz ...
Starting to download oauth-1.1.0.tgz (44,731 bytes)
............done: 44,731 bytes
6 source files, building
ERROR: could not chdir to /var/tmp/oauth/examples
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to create the missing directories:

```
sudo mkdir /var/tmp/oauth
sudo mkdir /var/tmp/oauth/examples
```